# why doesn't += work in a while true loop python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

the code just doesn't work, I can not understand what is wrong with the +=

```
taken = 1
first = int(input("   "))
while taken <= 6:
        print(1)
        print(taken+=1)
```

*the syntax error just pops up and the + is highlighted red,* I have tried looking however the only question I found was where it did not work because of the global the person put before the thing they were += onto.

Comment: All languages have a limited set of valid syntax, and this is just not defined as valid in python. There is no further explanation.

Comment: @Empty Head why do all answers and you print `1` as default? the program can do it by itself.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `variable  += val` is shorthand for
`variable = variable + val`
As this is an assignment expression, and doesn't return anything, that's why this is considered to be a syntax error.

> Note 1: This has nothing to do with while loop, it's universally unaccepted

> Note 2: Python doesn't support ++ / -- operators as of now

So, do this instead:

```
taken = 1
first = int(input("   "))
while taken <= 6:
        taken+=1
        print(f"1\n{taken}")
```

Comment: why all answers print `1` as default?  the program can do it by itself.

Comment: It's because the asker has that written in his code, so there may be some reason he wants to do so, therefore, w.o. changing that, I just concentrated on the actual question he's asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to write `taken += 1` in the row above and than print taken.

```
taken = 1
first = int(input("   "))
while taken <= 6:
        print(1)
        taken += 1
        print(taken)
```

Answer (score -1):

you simply cannot do that.
you can do this instead :

```
taken = 1
first = int(input("   "))
while taken <= 6:
        print(1)
        taken += 1
        print(taken)
```